# How do I solve this problem with Lyapunov functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Hi this is the system i need to work on:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot x&=&x(1-x)-axy\\
\dot y&=&y(1-y)-bxy
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I found four stationary points: $(0,0)$;$(1,0)$;$(0,1)$;$((a-1)/(ab-1),(b-1)/(ab-1))$

I found that $(0,0)$ is stable with linearization, but for the other three there are values of a and b for which i need to find a Lyapunov function and i have no idea where to start. The values being $a=1$ or $b=1$. Could you please give me any ideas?
Also what happens if I choose values for $a$ and $b$ like, for example, $2$ and $1/2$. The last point isn't defined anymore, does it just disappear from the phase portrait or what?
Anyway I'm quite confused, can anyone answer this questions please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can just try $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$?